# I'm trying to bind tasks to buttons, but I don't understand why it isn't working. Here's my code:

Tags: javascript

```
var bindShopEvents = function(shopListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {

    console.log("Binding shop events to their functions");//for testing

    var checkBox = shopListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    var editButton = shopListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
    var deleteButton = shopListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

    editButton.onclick = editList;

    deleteButton.onclick = deleteList;

    checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;

}
```

Comment: are you calling "bindShopEvents somewhere? Is that somewhere After the DOM has completed loading?

Comment: What does `console.log(editList);` say?

Comment: Thast's what it outputs                                          function () {
console.log("editList");//for tests
}

Comment: And here's where i'm calling "bindShopEvents"       for (var i = 0 ; i < unPurchased.length ; i++) {
 bindShopEvents(unPurchased.children[i], unPurch);
}

Comment: Maybe I should post the whole code as far as I've gotten?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event handler either using attachEvent (IE9)

So the code that does that would look like this:

```
editButton.attachEvent('onclick', editList);
editButton.addEventListener('click', editList , false);
```

Similarly for other elements that you want to attach events to.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function with `()` or it will not run.

eg:

```
editButton.onclick = editList();
```

BTW, I'm always using this workaround for event triggers and it works just fine, I never used the `.onclick` method

```
editButton.addEventListener("click", editList());
```